# How to automatically keep remote mercurial repository at tip after pushes

Tags: mercurial

I created a mercurial repository on some file servers net share.

Is it possible to automatically get the remote repository updated to `tip` if somebody pushes its changes?

Because some other people (purely users) may copy the repositories content (rather than cloning, because of lack of .hg) and i want them to get the newest version.

Since it is a share on a simple NAS it would be good if the pushing client could invoke this update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that a hook on the `changegroup` event can solve this.

Add the following lines to the repository's configuration file (repo/.hg/hgrc)

```
[hooks]
changegroup = hg update
```

This solution was suggested on a slightly different question:
[Cloning mercurial repo to the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831645/cloning-mercurial-repo-to-the-remote-host?rq=1)

At least under windows this seems only to work on local repositories. The reason for this is, that `hg` tries run a `cmd` on the remote path that fails, since it does not support UNC paths as current direcory.

Adding explicitly the repository url fixes this, but its not client independent anymore.

```
[hooks]
changegroup = hg update -R %HG_URL%
```

Answer (score 0):

You could treat the server repository as your "local working directory" and then PULL from your own PC to that location. If you use `hg pull --update` then it will automatically update the working folder to the latest.

One way to do this is to login to your NAS and physically run the hg command line program there. If not, you could also mount the NAS folder on your local PC and then chdir to its mapped local folder and use your local hg client to do so.

This might seem like an odd thing to do but Mercurial doesn't care which is the "clone" and which is the "server", you can swap them interchangeably in your workflow.

Comment: i know how to manually update it to tip. the question is about doing this automatically by the pushing client. e.g by some repository-setting/attribute that tells the client to do some custom command after a push

Comment: Hi vlad, I understood the question but I'm not aware of a way to do that (not saying there isn't some way) so I suggested an alternative approach which would achieve the same thing.

Comment: i think i found a solution (added answer) or are there any downsides (beside of the security implications - but the repository is in a trusted environment)?